# Sierra no sound in headphones after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, headphones

If my headphones are plugged in, after going to sleep my Mac doesn't have any sound in headphones. After re-plugging, everything works well. Sometimes, changing the output in `sys/Sound` works, but not always. 
I'm on MacBook Pro 2017, Sierra 10.12.6

Is there a solution to this? While working I need to put laptop to sleep frequently, and I don't want to mess with the headphones jack too much on daily basis. If any additional info needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
sudo pkill coreaudiod
```

This means:

1. unload sound kernel module,
2. reload sound kernel module,
3. stop sound service, il will restart automatically.

Comment: The error didn't occur for a while now. If it will I'll try your solution, thanks.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using MacOS Catalina 10.15. Thank you!